# AR / VR Software Engineering

Tags: virtual-reality, augmented-reality

What is the primary difference between Augmented Reality and Virtual Reality software engineering?

Comment: This is not related to game development.

Comment: I would argue that it is. There are AR/VR games. Now whether or not this question is *too basic* to be on-topic is another issue; what practical problem is this solving?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference in concept is also the main difference from a software engineering perspective: AR needs a view of the real world, VR does not. Thus AR has the challenge of overlaying graphics onto a live view, while VR has the challenge of completely replacing the environment around the viewer.

Comment: Thank you, jhocking. This does answer my question. I'm trying to understand whether or not a software engineer would have experience with both Unity and other 3D tools, just one or a possible both.